# Creating a function so that user can input a string and search for matching string within a list of object and return search result of type list

Tags: string, list, object, matching

I have created a Class and a list of object using the class.

```
class Holiday:

def __init__(self, Destination:str ,Region:str ,Description:str ,Price:float ):
    self.__destination=Destination
    self.__region=Region
    self.__description=Description
    self.__price=Price
```

Now I would like to create a function so that users can input and search for a matching string within the list of objects using the following function.

```
def SearchBasedOnRegionOrDescription( searchStr: str, myholiday: list[object]) -> list[object]:
```

I've tried

```
def SearchBasedOnRegionOrDescription( searchStr: str, myholiday: list[object]) -> list[object]:
    for myholiday[object] in myholiday:
        if myholiday[object].getDestination()==searchStr:
            print(myholiday[object].getDestination(), myholiday[object].getRegion(), myholiday[object].getDescription(), myholiday[object].getPrice())
```

But the code does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a wild guess trying to understand what you meant by "the code does not work":

```py
class Holiday:

    def __init__(self, destination:str, region:str, description:str, price:float):
        self.destination = destination
        self.region = region
        self.description = description
        self.price = price
        

def search_based_on_region_or_description(searched_name: str, holidays_to_search_in: list[object]) -> list[object]:
    return [
        current_holiday_examined for current_holiday_examined in holidays_to_search_in
        if searched_name in current_holiday_examined.region or searched_name in current_holiday_examined.description
    ]
```